# fetch mysql data in the second textbox while typing in first textbox

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

This is the screen

[image]

the php file named "fetching_book_title_for_barcode.php".

```
<?php
require_once('db.php');

$response=array();

$sql="select book_title from book where barcode_id LIKE '%".$_POST['value']."%'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){

    $book_title=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $response["book_title1"]=$book_title;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);   
?>
```

Here is the java script file with some ajax call.

```
var searchTimeout;//Timer to wait a little before fetching the data
$("#barcode_id_textBox").keyup(function() {
    var searchKey = this.value;

    clearTimeout(searchTimeout);

    searchTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        barcodeTextboxFill(searchKey);    
    }, 400); //If the key isn't pressed 400 ms, we fetch the data
});
function barcodeTextboxFill(searchKey){
     $.ajax({
        url: 'fetching_book_title_for_barcode.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {value: searchKey},
        success: function(data) {
                $("#book_title_textBox").val(data);
        }
    }); 

}
```

The HTML

```
<input type="text" id="barcode_id_textBox">
<input type="text" id="book_title_textBox">
```

`I am making Library management system for my university according to their requirements.

In MySql database i have a table of book in which i inserted the book records in which one of the column is for barcode id and one of the column is for book title.

I have an html page on which i have 2 inline textboxes, one of which is for barcode id and the other one is for book title.

Now i want that when barcode id is entered then at the same time the book title fetched from the database and showed in the book title's textbox.

I tried alot on it but i didn't find any solution. I tried it through ajax but i didn't get the required answer. what is the problem in it?

everyone help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way to do that is by writing some AJAX code

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ and use sql to populate the JS array

Comment: @Ryan how i only use to fetch the mysql data with autocomplete?

Comment: I thought that you wanted to autocomplete the box you're filling in. If you want to fill the other box then ajax is definitely the way to go like @RiggsFolly said

Comment: @RiggsFolly now you can see the snippet and the ajax code which i used but it is still not working, what could be the problem in my code?

Comment: @RiggsFolly what is the problem in my code, i am still not getting the exact answer. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [AJAX](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/) and [jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/).

In your text box add an `onChange` like so, `<input type="text" id="barcodeTextBox" onChange="BarcodeBoxFill()">`, the onChange will call the JS function `BarcodeBoxFill()` whenever the text box is altered.

Then the JS function should take the input from the box, `var text = $('#barcodeTextBox').val()`

Then on the same function should be your AJAX call which passed the value of the text box as a parameter. Then in the page the AJAX calls will be some SQL that gets the right value for the other box, (in this case the book title). As the `success` part of the AJAX you can change the value of the other text box,

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#bookTitleTextBox').val(data);
}`
```

Comment: @Arthur can you help me in this issue please?

Comment: You're not calling the function. You need the call the function in the HTML inputs, by using onChange="barcodeTextBoxFill()"

Comment: and i used the keyup event as you can see in my code and that is also correct but my code is still not working. :(

Comment: maybe just try changing your php to just echo something to try and see where the problem is. Also try checking your console on your browser (F12 for chrome) to see if theres any errors

Comment: i did it now but still getting no result. I don't know what is the issue? though my code is correct :( i saw it on console of my browser and there is no syntax error. :(

Comment: Have you included jquery at the start of your document. The Ajax your using is part of jquery